# How to clear @Lob field from database

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0, ebean

I want to clear a @Lob field from a Model.

In the model I have something like this for the image field:

```
@Lob
public byte[] image;
```

If I do something like this:

```
theModel.image = null;
theModel.update();
```

It doesn't remove the data from the field. I find this useful because not every time the model is updated (from a form) an image will be submited to modify the existing one.

But, what can I do to remove the image when needed?
Is there an in-framework way to do this?
WIll I have to update it "manually" (i.e.: sql...)?

Comment: TIP: don't keep files in DB, it's _expensive_, imho it's better to keep them in file system and in DB store only paths (preferably relative, as they're shorter)

Comment: see i.e. this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3751/1066240